# How to validate birthdate input box with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I validate the following input box creating a function without using any jQuery plugins?

This is what I was doing up till now and found out that the function **parseDate** is used from a plugin so this will not work for me.

**.js file code:**

```
function isBirthdate(valor){
 if (parseDate(valor, "dd-MM-yyyy"))
    return true;
 else
    return false;   
}
```

**.php file jQuery code:**

```
    if (isBirthdate($('#fecha_nacimiento').val()) == true){
        errormasg('#fecha_nacimiento',"<?php echo     JText::_('COM_CSTUDOMUS_NUMERIC_TEXTO_FORMATO');?>");
        return false;
    }
```

**.php file input box code:**

```
<input name="fecha_nacimiento" id="fecha_nacimiento" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('COM_CSTUDOMUS_DATE_FORMAT'); ?>" value="<?php echo JHtml::date($userData->fecha_nacimiento, 'd-m-Y'); ?>" tabindex="6">
```

Im importing the .js file correctly so there is no issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by doing the following:

**.js file code:**

```
function isValidateDate(valor){
    var regexpre = new RegExp(/\b\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{4}\b/);
        if (valor.match(regexpre))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

**.php file jQuery code:**

```
if (isValidateDate($('#fecha_nacimiento').val()) == false){
    errormasg('#fecha_nacimiento',"<?php echo JText::_('COM_CSTUDOMUS_FECHA_NAC');?>");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression :

```
var pattern =new RegExp(/^([0-9]{2})\-([0-9]{2})\-([0-9]{4})$/);
```

Then test your value :

```
if (pattern.test($('#fecha_nacimiento').val()) == true){
    errormasg('#fecha_nacimiento',"<?php echo       JText::_('COM_CSTUDOMUS_NUMERIC_TEXTO_FORMATO');?>");
    return false;
}
```